# Liferay CE: Is there any way to set access permissions to a single user to a single resource?

Tags: liferay

I'm trying to set user based permissions in Liferay CE 7, but the interface doesn't let me select access permissions to a single user, but rather to groups.

We would like that a document uploaded to the documents and media content could only be seen by a single user and the administrators, not the whole group.

Any tips on how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Liferay permissions always go through a role our it's little sister, a team. Any individual user handled in permissions would just not scale.

It used to be implemented in ancient versions (pre 5.x I believe) but was removed for performance reasons looooong time ago

Comment: So, if for example we store the payrolls of our employees, and we want for each employee to see only it's own payrolls, how would we go about it?

Comment: That's a completely different question. You're not forced to use Liferay's permission system, you can also implement your own application dependent one - especially for this case. Access the content through the *LocalService, which doesn't have any permission checks and add your own business-specific checks to make sure someone has access to this document (which is otherwise only accessible to e.g. HR)

Comment: Ok! That makes more sense! Thank you for your input!